# Why can't I display Unicode from SQLite?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, unicode

I want to display text from SQLite in my app, but it gets displayed wrong.

Example:
- In SQLite file, the text is: Hồ Chí Minh
- In my app, the text is : H·ªì Ch√≠ Minh

I tried with this code, but not success :

```
const char *cauhoichar = [[dic valueForKey:@"cauhoi"]         
cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
cauhoiText.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cauhoichar];
```

Answer (score 1):

The native code set of SQLite databases is indeed UTF-8 (sometimes UTF16[{be|le}] - with SQLiteManager you can see which is applied). Depending on the CodePage of your application (OS? Language?) you see different interpretations.